# How to write JUnit test cases for Settings.Global methods?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, powermock

Could you please support to write Junit test for the following functions storeDataScrollableFromSWC() and readDataScrollableFromSWC()? These belong to a viewmodel class. I tried multiple ways, but could not succeed.

```
@HiltViewModel
public class ViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
public static final String SCROLL_FROM_SWC = "SCROLL_FROM_SWC";
public static final int CHECKED_STATE = 1;
public static final int UN_CHECKED_STATE = 0;
private static final int DEFAULT_VALUE = 0;

@Inject
public InputSettingViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
}

public void storeDataScrollableFromSWC(boolean state) {
    int intValue = state ? CHECKED_STATE : UN_CHECKED_STATE;
    Settings.Global.putInt(getApplication().getContentResolver(), SCROLL_FROM_SWC, intValue);
}

public int readDataScrollableFromSWC() {
    return Settings.Global.getInt(getApplication().getContentResolver(), SCROLL_FROM_SWC, DEFAULT_VALUE);
}
```